# Handling parallel promises using native implementation in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous

Chrome (at least the beta I'm using) now has promises implemented in native JavaScript, and, based on a few experiments, it's working OK. There's lots of documentation about the "then" and "catch" methods, and I'm able to chain promises together so that, when one is fulfilled, the next one is then waited on.

However, I want to know how to wait for promises in parallel, with a callback function called when they ALL fulfill or reject. In such a case, all of the results and reasons have to be available as well, perhaps in an array.

Dumping the JavaScript object ("Promise"), I see a method "all", but I can't locate documentation for it.

Can anyone supply info on this?

I've also implemented my own experimental parallel mechanism, which looks like this:

```
function async1_promise() {
    return new Promise(
        function(resolve, reject) {
            async_call1(
                function () {
                    resolve("async_call1 worked!");
                }
            );
        }
    );
}

function async2_promise() {
    return new Promise(
        function(resolve, reject) {
            async_call2(
                function () {
                    resolve("async_call2 worked!");
                }
            );
        }
    );
}

function async3_promise() {
    return new Promise(
        function(resolve, reject) {
            async_call3(
                function () {
                    resolve("async_call3 worked!");
                }
            );
        }
    );
}

parallel([async1_promise(), async2_promise(), async3_promise()],
    function (promises, results) {
        console.log('all done', promises, results);
    }
);

function parallel(promises, callback) {
    var results = [];
    promises.forEach(
        function (val, key, array) {
            val.then(
                function (result) {
                    results[key] = {
                        success: true,
                        result: result
                    };
                    if (results.length == promises.length)
                        callback(promises, results);
                },
                function (reason) {
                    results[key] = {
                        success: false,
                        result: reason
                    };
                    if (results.length == promises.length)
                        callback(promises, results);
                }
            );
        }
    );
}
```

Comments on my attempt to handle parallel promises are welcome as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Promise.all` accepts an array of Promise instances and will only proceed once they are all resolved or one is rejected.

Once all the promises have resolved it will give you an array of results in the same order as was passed to `Promise.all` so you can access all the responses,
or the first reject encountered will trigger the `catch`.

Using your example, the following can replace your `parallel` function:

```
Promise.all([async1_promise(), async2_promise(), async3_promise()])
    .then(function(results) {
        // results = ["async_call1 worked!", "async_call2 worked!", "async_call3 worked!"]          
    })
    .catch(err) {
        // error handling
        // only called once for the first reject encountered
    });
```

**Useful Links**

- https://github.com/domenic/promises-unwrapping - ES6 promises spec
- [V8 Promise source](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/promise.js) - See `PromiseAll` for implementation
- [MDN Promise Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Static_methods) - not Chrome but uses same spec and has usage example
- [html5rocks.com promises tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) - contains a section on using `.all`

Comment: Thanks! Is the above documented anywhere? Did you get it from the source code? Any other reference you can supply?

Comment: I've added a few links to the spec, source and usage examples

Comment: Does `.all` do things in parallel?

Comment: .all accepts an iterable as parameter, therefore it will iterate over the content, not do something magically parallel :-)

Comment: @Shamoon @echox `Promise.all` accepts an array of promises; those promises will resolve or reject in parallel as soon as they're created. `Promise.all` simply waits for them all to resolve, or any one of them to reject ... it has no ability to enforce serial execution of those promises. Executing Promises in series isn't handled by the ES6 native Promise implementation, some more info here http://www.datchley.name/promise-patterns-anti-patterns/

Comment: Why do you call the promises in the array ? You just need to give pointers to them Promise.all([async1_promise, async2_promise, async3_promise]). For me it does not work otherwise (Node 6)